# Page not rendering properly in IE8

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer-8, localhost, compatibility

Sigh. Yes, it's an IE8 problem, again.

So, this page: http://pointsgateway.inteltechnologyprovider.com/ - doesn't display properly when using IE8, usually I'd accept this and move on but the client works exclusively in IE8 and won't be amending this anytime soon (sound familiar?!). My issue is that, it's based in Drupal (of which I have 0% exposure to) and I can only seem to amend the PHP and CSS file...

Is there a, relatively, straight forward issue to fix? Have I missed something?

Viewing the files locally (saving the web page info and then viewing in the browsers - IE8 et al) displays fine so I *assume* that this is a server side filter issue (wherein *something* isn't pulling through)?

Frustratingly yours,

Comment: I doubt it's a server issue when IE is involved. I'm going to assume it's a browser one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as thought the fix was to duplicate some of the elements so that IE8 doesn't ignore the "width" properties as well as the "float" properties. IE8 doesn't like media queries, duplicating these as separate elements in the code, outside of the @media queries blocks worked!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an IE8 problem and you missing tags
you need to make sure you close all  s tags
ie8 will not work fine if you ignore any tag , use dreamweaver to get your missing tags

Comment: It _was_ an IE8 problem, however this was aimed at IE8 not recognising media queries. I resolved this by adding the classes in question _outside_ of the media queries and thusly, IE8 picked up these. I would never use Dreamweaver to resolve an issue as it's, inherently, a poor system.